# Voice Alteration Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

Could somebody point me to a voice alteration algorithm? Preferably in Java or C? Something that I could use to change a stream of recorded vocals into something that sounds like Optimus Prime. (FYI- Optimus Prime is the lead Autobot from transformers with a very distinctive sounding voice... not everybody may know this.) Is there an open source solution?

Comment: Was OP's voice much altered?  Personally, I found the voice-acting in Transformers to be pretty unremarkable.  It could well have been worse though -- think of all those animated films where the voices are provided by people who got where they are because of their looks.

Comment: I wasn't implying the Optimus' voice was altered. Rather I was asking if I could change an average person's voice into his.

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever manage to find something?

Comment: No, I never did find an easy to understand or implement answer. I'm still looking.

Comment: After rereading this question I investigated some more and found what could be promising. I posted a little info on my blog: http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/vocoding-fun

Answer (score 3):

You can't just change the sample rate. The human voice has formants. What you want to do is move the formants. That should be your line of research.

Read about vocoders and filter banks.

---

Could you provide a link as example? I haven't seen the film so I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is an open-source wave editor which includes effect filters - since it's open source you could see what algorithms they use.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what it sounded like, I figured it would be a vocoder, but after listening to a few samples, it's definitely not a vocoder (or if it is, it's pretty low in the mix.)  It sounds like maybe there's a short, fast delay effect on it, along with some heavy EQ to make it sound kind of like a tiny AM radio, and maybe a little ring modulator.  I think that a LOT of the voice actor's voice is coming through relatively intact, so a big part of the sound is just getting your own voice to sound right, and no effects will do that part for you.

All the above info is just me guessing based on having messed around with a lot of guitar pedals over the years, and done some amateur recording and sound-effects making, so I could be way off.

Comment: That makes sense. He could use a high-pass filter instead of EQ maybe. A good oversampling digital ring modulator would be nice. That's what they used for the Daleks in Doctor Who.