# How to change a recorded voice to a man's voice in Core Audio (Audio Unit/ Remote IO) for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, audio-recording, audiounit

I am new to Core Audio and really lost, I am trying to record an audio and then apply voice modulation to that recording and play it back. I have looked at the example Speak Here which uses Audio Queue for audio recording. I am stuck at the part of how to change the audio samples. I understand that it can be done using Audio Unit in the call back function to change the audio samples, but I have no idea what to apply to those samples to change them (will changing pitch help ?).

If you could direct me to some source code or tutorial or any site that explains voice modulation for objective C will really really help me. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158950/voice-alteration-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is not that simple. Basically, you would have to implement a vocoder ("voice-coder") to change a voice. The [Wikipedia links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder#External_links) should help you there.

Then, you still have manipulate those samples in CoreAudio. You can do this using [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) but that not exactly an easy-to-use API. It might actually be less trouble to use one of the simpler CoreAudio APIs and wrap your vocoder in an Audio Unit.

Do you have some experience with audio processing? Implementing a vocoder without some prior knowledge about audio processing in general is a tough task.

Answer (score 2):

First, to actually answer your question:  When you called the AudioQueueNewInput() function, you pass it the name of a routine that will be called every time data is available to you.  You probably called it MyInputBufferHandler() or something.  It's third argument is an AudioQueueBufferRef which hold the incoming data.

Be aware that this is not as simple as looking at each sample (amplitude) and lowering or raising it.  You receive samples in the temporal (time) domain as amplitudes.  There is no pitch or frequency information available.  What you need to do is move the incoming samples (waveform) into the frequency domain, wherein each "point" in that space is a frequency and it's accompanying power and phase.  You can do that with an FFT (fast Fourier transform) but the mathematics are somewhat sophisticated.  Apple does provide FFT routines in the Acceleration framework, but be aware that you are wading into very deep water here.